# Understanding the amount of GCP billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, invoice

I work at an advertising agency.
I would like to know the amount of GCP invoiced as accurately as possible before the invoice arrives, and I would like to know where I can check that on the Partner Sales Console.

I know I can check the tabs in the dashboard, but there was a discrepancy with the amount on the invoice, and I would like to know if there is a way to get a more accurate picture.

Comment: Enable the export of billing data to BigQuery. Label each resource that you want to track.

Comment: Did you try to go to Menu>Billing>cost table?